# Hibernate 3.5 hangs on query, which has ~7500 IN parameters, but works when use_sql_comments is enabled. Why?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, freeze

Basically, when the program (Java, IDE is Intellij on Ubuntu) executes the loadAll() Hibernate method, a query is made to an Oracle database. The query itself is quite complicated (the main problem, in my opinion, is the IN condition, which has ~7500 values and also comes from the same database).

Usually, the program hangs on this query without any sort of error message or anything. I tried increasing JVM memory, looking at fetchSize and the sort, but nothing helped. I tried to debug the problem and added, among other things, a Hibernate setting called use_sql_comments. After that, the program started working like a charm, except now I could see that about 30 copies of the same query were being logged.

My guess is that this flag somehow divides the IN parameters or something like that (7500 values / 30 queries = 250 values). What I can't understand is why this specific flag, which is most likely there for debugging purposes, doing this?